# Why the conditional div is not working in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I have three conditional **div** in a page and trying to show each div on a certain condiiton.

```
<div *ngIf="isAvailable=='true'">
    <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Admin">Deployment Admin</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" aria-describedby="name" [(ngModel)]="NewDeployAdmin.name">
                  </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Enter email" [(ngModel)]="NewDeployAdmin.email">

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="paswsword" name="password" placeholder="Password" placeholder="Enter al least 6 character" [(ngModel)]="NewDeployAdmin.password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="fnCreateDeployAdmin()">Submit</button>
    </form>   
</div>

<div *ngIf="isAvailable=='false'">
<button  type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="fnDisableAccount()">Disable Account</button> | <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="fnUpdateDeployAdmin()">Reset Credential</button>
</div>
```

In **.ts** page, I set the **isAvailable** on different condition and want to display the corresponding **div**. But it is not working.

I want to render the corresponding **div**. Here is the code where I am setting the **isAvailable**

```
isDeploymentAdminAvailable(deployment){
  let customQuery = {
    equalTo: this.selectedDeploy.key
  }

  this.authService.fnGetDataUsingCustomQuery(FirebaseDb.firebasedeploymentAdminTable, customQuery).subscribe(
    (rec: any) => {
      rec.forEach((reccord: any) => {
        reccord.key = reccord.$key;
      });
      this.deployAdminData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rec));

    });

  if(this.deployAdminData!=null && Object.keys(this.deployAdminData).length>0){
    return "true";

  }

  return "false";

}
```

And the function from where I am calling this **isDeploymentAdminAvailable** method is

```
deploymentOnClick($event, deployment){ 

    this.isAvailable = 'None';

    this.selectedDeploy = deployment;

     this.isAvailable = this.isDeploymentAdminAvailable(deployment);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning `"true"` and `"false"` those are strings that both evaluate to true. Remove the quotes so that it is `true` and `false` and set the type of `isAvailable` to  `boolean`. and let the *ngIf compare `isAvailable` or `!isAvailble`

Honestly there is a lot wrong with your code. Javascript is single threaded you should have your return statements be determinate. i.e. the `if` should be followed by `else`. I only see two conditional divs... Using `true` `false` or None is not a good idea at all. The names `true` and `false` imply a binary relationship if you want more than two options you should use other terms.

Also this is typescript. You need to type your parameters. They are all of type `any`.

Also you pass deployment into `isDeploymentAdminAvailable` and don't use it anywhere...

Also in javascript you need to use the `===` and `!==` operators wherever possible.

Please describe the behavior occuring. Are you not rendering either div? Please change `isAvailable` to a boolean and tell me what is happening. Use `console.log` in the `if` statement and outside and check the console to see which condition is being satisfied and if that's what you expect. When you make these changes report back and I will help you.

As @yurzui stated the issue with your code is almost certainly that you are not using asynchronous code. You are waiting for firebase to return a value and then immediately checking that value before it returns. I would imagine that the code now is always returning `"false"` since `this.deployAdminData` will always be `null` since you're not waiting for the response from firebase and just running right through it.

To fix it, one approach would be to separate the `if` condition into a separate function and call that function at the end of `subscribe`.

```
this.authService.fnGetDataUsingCustomQuery(FirebaseDb.firebasedeploymentAdminTable, customQuery).subscribe(
    (rec: any) => {
      rec.forEach((reccord: any) => {
        reccord.key = reccord.$key;
      });
      this.deployAdminData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rec));
      this.isAvailable = this.yourFunctionName(deployAdminData);
    });
}

yourFunctionName(deployAdminData: any) {
  if(deployAdminData !== null && 
  Object.keys(deployAdminData).length > 0) {
    return true;    
  } else { return false; }  
}
```

also edit this:

```
deploymentOnClick($event, deployment){ 
//this.isAvailable = 'None';
  this.selectedDeploy = deployment;
  this.isDeploymentAdminAvailable(deployment);
}
```

Then you can use `*ngIf="isAvailable"`. Note I set `deployAdminData` to type `any` in the parameter. That is not best practice and you need to replace `any` with the data type.

Comment: He also getting data asynchronously but returns value immediately

Comment: Yes @yurzui that seems to be the issue in this case and my answer reflects that.

Comment: I am not returning a true and false here. I am returning a string. Based on the return value, I want to display the mentioned three divs. But it is not working.

Comment: Yes @yurzui I think returning value immediately is the problem. How to overcome this ? I have no idea.

Comment: "It is not working" is not even close to being a legitimate description of a a problem in computer programming.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `I would imagine that the code now is always returning "false" since this.deployAdminData` is happenning actually. How can I wait for getting the data and then set is isAvailable ?

Answer (score 0):

The basic reason why `isAvailable` isn't controlling your div visibility has already been given - the value should be set within the subscribe.

But it is clear that the application does **not** work when the type of this flag is changed to Boolean.

It seems to me, the logic of the app is that before the data is fetched, you **show neither** of the div's (`isAvailable === 'None'`), then after fetch you show one or the other div based on the value returned.

### Refactoring according to Angular best practice

You might want to push the code in `isDeploymentAdminAvailable` into the `authService` service.

That way

- all logic related to the fetch is in one place
- your testing will go smoother
- you can remove dependency of Firebase from the component
- expose the data and the `isAvailable` property as Observables.

**Observable conventions**

It's common practice to append `$` to the end of variables that are observable, to make it obvious that they need `async` pipe in the template, or `subscribe` in the ts code.

### Why observable variables?

The app will render the page long before the Firebase fetch returns a value, so by using observable variables and the `async` pipe in your template, the view will automatically update when the fetch eventually returns.

Also, Firebase can push new values to your app when the database changes, so with observable properties the view responds to these changes without need to explicitly refresh.

The only thing that's not clear to me is the relationship between `NewDeployAdmin` and `this.deployAdminData`.
You may need to add a `subscribe()` or an `async` pipe depending on how these two items are related.

**authService.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  public deployAdminData$ = new BehaviorSubject({});
  public isAvailable$ = new BehaviorSubject('None');  // initial value set to 'None'

  private fnGetDataUsingCustomQuery(...) {
    ...
  }

  public isDeploymentAdminAvailable(key) {
    let customQuery = {
      equalTo: key
    }
    this.fnGetDataUsingCustomQuery(FirebaseDb.firebasedeploymentAdminTable, customQuery)
      .subscribe(rec => {
        rec.forEach(reccord => reccord.key = reccord.$key );
        const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rec));  // this may not be needed
        this.deployAdminData$.next(data);
        this.isAvailable$.next( 
          data && Object.keys(data).length ? 'true' : 'false';
        )
      });
}
```

**myComponent.html**

```html
<div *ngIf="(isAvailable$ | async)=='true'">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Admin">Deployment Admin</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" 
       aria-describedby="name" [(ngModel)]="NewDeployAdmin.name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" 
       aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Enter email" 
       [(ngModel)]="NewDeployAdmin.email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="paswsword" name="password" 
        placeholder="Password" placeholder="Enter at least 6 characters" 
        [(ngModel)]="NewDeployAdmin.password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary 
      (click)="fnCreateDeployAdmin()">Submit</button>
  </form>   
</div>

<div *ngIf="(isAvailable$ | async)=='false'">
  <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" 
   (click)="fnDisableAccount()">Disable Account</button>
  <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
   (click)="fnUpdateDeployAdmin()">Reset Credential</button>
</div>
```

**myComponent.ts**

```js
// Set up observable pipeline that responds to changes in the database.
private isAvailable$ = this.authService.isAvailable$;
private this.deployAdminData$ = this.authService.this.deployAdminData$;

isDeploymentAdminAvailable(deployment) {
  this.authService.isDeploymentAdminAvailable(this.selectedDeploy.key)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of comparing and using expression in the template, directly pass the value **isAvailable** to template.

```
<div *ngIf="isAvailable">
   ...
</div>    
<div *ngIf="!isAvailable">
   ...
</div>
```

I hope it might help.

Comment: Since `isAvailable` is of type `string` how would this suggestion work lol.

Comment: @Zachscs type can be changed and looking at the variable name it should be of type boolean. what do you suggest?

Comment: I wrote an answer. The askers issue is not related to this. This answer does not come close to addressing the issue.

Comment: isAvailable is not boolean type here. Thats why I have checked the conditions.